# Arrow key is not working for changing button selection in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

When I try to delete a netbeans project, I get this dialog

[image: dialog]

I try to use left arrow key to switch focus from the No to the Yes button but it isn't switching. (This will work perfectly for any other windows application on my system)

Is this a normal behaviour for netbeans IDE or is something wrong with mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried it with the latest development build, and I can confirm that the arrow keys do not move the focus.

My guess is that it is a Java/Swing/AWT thing, not necessarily a Netbeans thing. Unfortunately I do not have another Java application I can get to at this very moment, so the previous sentence is *conjecture* on my part.

On the other hand, <kbd>TAB</kbd>/<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> cycles through each of the UI items. A little bit farther around the mountain, but not quite as far as reaching for the mouse.